# The css effect does not work when scrolling in Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.50?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, chromium

I don’t know if **Microsoft Edge** was updated to **version 88** today or yesterday. I have a `css` effect that requires 100vh or 100% and the page cannot be **scrolled**.

CSS Parallax
https://codepen.io/iAmNathanJ/pen/pvLQJY

There is no problem displaying in codepen

But this effect is **difficult to scroll** when the current **Microsoft Edge version 88 tab is opened**, which was possible before. **Chrome everything is fine**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open\+Sans:100,400,700");
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: #418eab;
}
h1 {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  padding: 4rem 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  padding: 0 0 4rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  text-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.parallax {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.mountains {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}
.peak,
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.peak.p0,
.logo.p0 {
  transform: translateZ(-40px) scale(41);
}
.peak.p1,
.logo.p1 {
  transform: translateZ(-25px) scale(26);
}
.peak.p2,
.logo.p2 {
  transform: translateZ(-15px) scale(16);
}
.peak.p3,
.logo.p3 {
  transform: translateZ(-8px) scale(9);
}
.peak.p4,
.logo.p4 {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(6);
}
.peak.p5,
.logo.p5 {
  transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
}
.peak.p6,
.logo.p6 {
  transform: translateZ(-3px) scale(4);
}
.peak.p7,
.logo.p7 {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
.peak.p8,
.logo.p8 {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.peak.p9,
.logo.p9 {
  transform: translateZ(-0.5px) scale(1.5);
}
.peak img,
.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110%;
  height: auto;
  left: -5%;
  bottom: -5%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#7168b5 0%, #418eab 50%, #83b6c9 100%);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.multiply {
  opacity: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
.logo {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}
.logo h1 {
  font-size: 10rem;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 25vw;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 50px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #83b6c9;
  z-index: 2;
}
article {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  max-width: 800px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="mountains">
    <div class="peak p0"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-0.svg" alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p1"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-1.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p2"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-2.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p3"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-3.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p4"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-4.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p5"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-5.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p6"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-6.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p7"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-7.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p8"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-8.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak p9"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nathanj-me/image/upload/v1424406215/mountain-9.svg " alt="mountain peak"/></div>
    <div class="peak">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>SCROLL</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <article title="Lorem">
      <h1>LOREM</h1>
      <p>This effect is achieved with pure CSS. See <a target="_blank" href="https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/">this article</a> for the technique.</p>
      <p>Single-origin coffee gastropub kale chips leggings try-hard. Roof party Brooklyn fap, bicycle rights organic disrupt food truck. Cred mustache chillwave selvage Banksy. Slow-carb artisan skateboard Thundercats, next level Brooklyn fixie. Forage photo booth sustainable 3 wolf moon, quinoa Bushwick direct trade viral gentrify cronut listicle ethical. Post-ironic readymade sriracha, drinking vinegar aesthetic gastropub messenger bag. Retro Echo Park meditation, ennui Kickstarter paleo fashion axe. Hashtag cardigan scenester distillery Banksy, lumbersexual gastropub. Pickled tousled retro, umami food truck biodiesel Austin. Hoodie Truffaut four dollar toast banh mi, artisan master cleanse narwhal flexitarian. Bespoke direct trade Williamsburg umami, paleo Carles synth. Mlkshk bitters scenester, mumblecore direct trade narwhal hella sriracha cliche leggings twee paleo wayfarers. American Apparel locavore street art, actually Carles trust fund ethical. Beard meh organic, try-hard pickled sriracha +1 small batch narwhal hella cornhole chambray synth drinking vinegar.</p>
      <p>Drinking vinegar quinoa fixie aesthetic organic, kale chips literally master cleanse Neutra Helvetica cardigan. Pickled brunch literally vegan viral 8-bit. Art party kogi gluten-free fingerstache, DIY pork belly put a bird on it hashtag 3 wolf moon tote bag chia. PBR&B Tumblr Austin, Odd Future XOXO vegan flexitarian keytar gastropub beard mumblecore skateboard lomo bespoke. Echo Park skateboard beard, migas farm-to-table Helvetica salvia. Cronut blog Truffaut, YOLO umami letterpress wayfarers church-key lo-fi. Ethical whatever banh mi tilde.</p>
      <p>Cronut lomo migas, Bushwick leggings Neutra 3 wolf moon scenester Kickstarter raw denim lo-fi cred tousled photo booth Truffaut. Fashion axe pug quinoa biodiesel stumptown, dreamcatcher bespoke McSweeney's Thundercats crucifix fingerstache keytar chambray cold-pressed. Quinoa tote bag letterpress, kale chips salvia Etsy Truffaut normcore twee butcher chia irony. Keytar wolf scenester, mixtape master cleanse Blue Bottle lomo leggings polaroid Carles stumptown fixie occupy fingerstache cardigan. Gastropub narwhal cred yr. Vice Brooklyn PBR street art Thundercats, VHS typewriter XOXO banh mi mustache normcore asymmetrical salvia viral kitsch. Umami trust fund paleo lumbersexual, scenester Schlitz cold-pressed sartorial artisan Williamsburg migas.</p>
      <p>Single-origin coffee gastropub kale chips leggings try-hard. Roof party Brooklyn fap, bicycle rights organic disrupt food truck. Cred mustache chillwave selvage Banksy. Slow-carb artisan skateboard Thundercats, next level Brooklyn fixie. Forage photo booth sustainable 3 wolf moon, quinoa Bushwick direct trade viral gentrify cronut listicle ethical. Post-ironic readymade sriracha, drinking vinegar aesthetic gastropub messenger bag. Retro Echo Park meditation, ennui Kickstarter paleo fashion axe. Hashtag cardigan scenester distillery Banksy, lumbersexual gastropub. Pickled tousled retro, umami food truck biodiesel Austin. Hoodie Truffaut four dollar toast banh mi, artisan master cleanse narwhal flexitarian. Bespoke direct trade Williamsburg umami, paleo Carles synth. Mlkshk bitters scenester, mumblecore direct trade narwhal hella sriracha cliche leggings twee paleo wayfarers. American Apparel locavore street art, actually Carles trust fund ethical. Beard meh organic, try-hard pickled sriracha +1 small batch narwhal hella cornhole chambray synth drinking vinegar.</p>
      <p>Drinking vinegar quinoa fixie aesthetic organic, kale chips literally master cleanse Neutra Helvetica cardigan. Pickled brunch literally vegan viral 8-bit. Art party kogi gluten-free fingerstache, DIY pork belly put a bird on it hashtag 3 wolf moon tote bag chia. PBR&B Tumblr Austin, Odd Future XOXO vegan flexitarian keytar gastropub beard mumblecore skateboard lomo bespoke. Echo Park skateboard beard, migas farm-to-table Helvetica salvia. Cronut blog Truffaut, YOLO umami letterpress wayfarers church-key lo-fi. Ethical whatever banh mi tilde.</p>
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My chrome doesn't work either (88.0.4324.104).
It should work, just add it to `.overflow` `background-attachment: fixed;`:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#7168b5 0%, #418eab 50%, #83b6c9 100%);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```